# Latex error: file 'tabu.sty' not found

Tags: packages

Hollow every one,

Iam beginner in latex. I have a problem when I build my pdf with latex. The following message error is always displayed:
Latex error: file 'tabu.sty' not found
or enter new name.< default extension: sty>

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably `tabu`  is not installed. Which distribution do you have?